# Find indices for rows with near duplicated values

Tags: r, duplicates

I have faced with the problem of finding near duplicates row in dataset.
For my data I have to add the column "POSSIBLE_DUPLICATES", which should contains indices of possible duplicates. Data contains not only field FNAME and LNAME, but some other, that also can be used for finding duplicates.

```
| id | FNAME  | LNAME   | POSSIBLE_DUPLICATES |
|----|--------|---------|---------------------|
| 1  | Aaron  | Golding | 2,3                 |
| 2  | Aroon  | Golding | 1,3                 |
| 3  | Aaron  | Golding | 2,1                 |
| 4  | John   | Bold    | 6                   |
| 5  | Markus | M.      |                     |
| 6  | John   | Bald    | 4                   |
```

I tried to find indicies with agrep() function, but I am not really understand, how I can invoke it for multiple columns and how to concat indicies for all rows. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using `agrep` on an added field ("match") that is the concatenation of selected fields that you want to use to identify duplicates with (add other fields as needed). In this example the list indices correspond to the rows of the data.frame.

```
# make a mock data.frame
df <- read.csv(textConnection("
id,FNAME,LNAME
1,Aaron,Golding
2,Aroon,Golding
3,Aaron,Golding
4,John,Bold
5,Markus,M.
6,John,Bald
"))

# string together the fields that might be matching and add to data.frame
df$match <- paste0(trimws(as.character(df$FNAME)), 
  trimws(as.character(df$LNAME)))

# make an empty list to fill in
possibleDups <- list()

# loop through each row and find matching strings
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  dups <- agrep(df$match[i], df$match)
  if(length(dups) != 1){possibleDups[[i]] <- dups[dups != i]} else {
    possibleDups[[i]] <- NA
  }
}

# proof - print the list of possible duplicates
print(possibleDups) 

> [[1]]
> [1] 2 3

> [[2]]
> [1] 1 3

> [[3]]
> [1] 1 2

> [[4]]
> [1] 6

> [[5]]
> [1] NA

> [[6]]
> [1] 4
```

If you just want a character string list of duplicates, you could use this loop instead of the previous one and delete the line that creates an empty list.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  dups = agrep(df$match[i], df$match)
  if(length(dups) != 1){df$possibleDups[i] <- paste(dups[dups != i], 
    collapse = ',')} else {
    df$possibleDups[i] <- NA
  }
}

print(df)

>   id  FNAME   LNAME        match possibleDups
> 1  1  Aaron Golding AaronGolding          2,3
> 2  2  Aaron Golding AaronGolding          1,3
> 3  3  Aaron Golding AaronGolding          1,2
> 4  4   John    Bold     JohnBold            6
> 5  5 Markus      M.     MarkusM.         <NA>
> 6  6   John    Bald     JohnBald            4
```

Comment: I think OP wants vectors as element of the data.frame, not comma separated strings, so you could add `unlist(possibleDups,recursive=FALSE)` as a new col (untested)

Comment: Also untested, likely to crash but fixable, to avoid the loops: `df$possible_duplicates <- Map(setdiff,lapply(df$match,agrep,df$match),1:nrow(df))`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper is `Map` from the purrr library?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, Thank you! Your solution is also works properly, but it seems that it as slow as loop for 1500 rows. So is any difference in performance between loop- and non-loop solution?

Comment: apply functions are not so different in speed thas simple loops, what goes faster is to use vectorized functions. I don't know agrep, I just typed it from my phone after seeing @jbdcode's answer, I'll take a look at it a bit later

Comment: @jbdcode the function I used is `base::Map`. It's different than `pure::map` . You may want to edit your answer as what you say about data.frame being unable to contain vectors is inaccurate

Comment: @Evgenij Can you tell us how much real data you have and what you want to do with it? Because these operations always take time so we may need to think outside the box if you want to win time, for example, typoses rarely occur on the first letter, so we could disqualify as duplicates the rows that don't contain same 1st letter for `FNAME` & `LNAME`, that'd be 100 times faster in the end.

Comment: Or to stay more rigorous to the initial approach we could disqualify all couples of rows who have a difference of character length of more than one. I'm not sure if agrep is smart enough to di it itself, it mightcompute the levenshtein distance for every couple, and apply the threshold parameters afterwards, which would be a waste of ressources in many cases.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper,I have about 130 000 rows with 30 fields in my data table. All that I have to do is find duplicates by first name, last name, job type and city and get indicies of duplicated row. All that field can containts misspelling or typing errors, so I can't find duplicates by exact match. After your answer I decided to do follow: `df$possible_duplicates_NAME <- Map(setdiff,parLapply(df$FNAME,agrep,df$FNAME),1:nrow(df))` for `fname` and the same thing for other fields. Then I just intercect final vectors, so in result I get the indices of duplicated rows.

Comment: I suppose that such solution is a little bit silly and slow. But since I newbie in R, I can't find any smarter way.

Comment: the lapply will compare each of 130.000 rows with the 130.000 rows, this query won't ever finish, but if it contains names you should have much less distinct values, so we can use this; can you update the question with the info you just gave me + the result of `summary(df[c("FNAME","LNAME",therestofyour30cols)])` ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper thanks for clarification in `base::map`. Re inserting a vector into a DF cell... maybe we are misinterpreting each other? Here is a demo of what I meant: `df = data.frame(someField = NA);df$someField[1] = 1:5` which results in "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". In trying to replicate the example table from the question, a vector of length > 1 is being added to a single row/col cell, which according to the demo is not possible. This would be a powerful feature of data.frame, but seems reserved for lists - can you show example?

Comment: If you take my solution and print df$possible duplicates[1] you will see that it's a vector. You can have a column of `data.frames` too :). You cannot assign them the way you did though because once the class of a data.frame column has been set you cannot put any element in it (same for characters and numerics).

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper that's awesome - thanks! I changed the post to remove the false statement. The more you know!